# Unable to do software reset in UART4

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart

I have my omap4460 pandaboard loaded with linux kernel 3.4.I have unbinded the driver from uart4 instance using `echo -n omap_uart.3 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/omap_uart/unbind`.

I have written a new driver using simple `struct file_operations`

Now after the pad configuration when I do a software reset and wait for its completion the loop does not come out of the loop.

```
l = ioread32(io_map + 0x54);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SYSC value before = %x\n", l);
    iowrite32(0x2,io_map + 0x54);
    l = ioread32(io_map + 0x54);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SYSC value after = %x\n", l);
    readval = ioread32(io_map + 0x58);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SYSS read value = %x\n", readval);
    while((readval & 0x1)== 0);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "software reset completed\n");
```

io_map is the address obtained from the call

```
io_map = ioremap(UART4_BASE,UART_SIZE);
```

where UART_SIZE is 0x83 a nd UART4_BASE is 0x4806eooo.
1st and 2nd printk statements give the same value 0.

Comment: Well, I have no experience with Kernel modules, but to me it looks like you are assigning a value to readval and then you loop on it forever. How should 'readval' change within that loop?

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer - I'm guessing the interrupt-handler changes it?  Prob. needs volatile?

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer:Setting the 1st bit of the SYSC register will immediately set the 0th bit of SYSS register to 1.However the result is the same even after the edit.

Comment: @MartinJames:Where am I supposed to give volatile? Even if I skip the software reset the value written to DLL,LCR register is not reflected.Somewhere the register is getting updated.